# PaperTrail Ruby gem for Node

Tags: node.js, ruby

When I searched for the Node equivalent of the Ruby gem PaperTrial, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778049/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-papertrail-gem-in-rails-for-nodejs) stackoverflow question.

There is also [node-audit-log](https://github.com/ccraigc/node-audit-log).  However, it has not be touched in 2 years.  And furthermore, it does not seem to audit/log CRUD actions.

If there is not equivalent node package, please let me know how the node community handles model auditing/logging, specifically for CRUD actions or versioning of model data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.